# How to create a custom NSSlider with a transparent middle bar and custom knob size

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsslider

I've searched around for some code on `NSSliderCell` but I can't find a way to do what I'm looking for.
I'd like to create something like this (where the white line is the slider knob, 1 pixel width):

[image]

I'm going to use this for the time bar of a music track, so it's going to move every second (that's why I want to use a `NSSlider` to make things easy).
What do I need to do to make a slider, with a transparent middle bar, similar to the image above?


PS: It's not going to be touchable, it's just for display.

Comment: I would just draw the thing as a line on a view in Core Graphics.  Also, your question appears phrased as though you're looking for someone to write it for you...

Comment: no, i just need some directions on how to do it. i'll rephrase it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it:

- I created a `NSSliderCell` subclass with a property `@property float x`;
- I overrode the `drawKnob` method and inside it I wrote:

> -(void)drawKnob:(NSRect)knobRect{ self.x = knobRect.origin.x; }

- I dragged a `NSSlider` into my window (made it small, changed it's width to the window's width) and changed it's cell class to the one I created;
- And then when the music is playing, every time a second goes by I do:

> ```
> [_timeBarSlider setMinValue:0];
> [_timeBarSlider setMaxValue:myTrack.duration];
> [_timeBarSlider setDoubleValue:myPlayer.currentPosition];
> [[_timeBarImageView animator] setFrame:NSMakeRect(_timeBarSliderCell.x, yourYCoordinate, yourWidth, yourHeight)];
> ```

`_timerBarSlider` is the NSSlider I have in IB / `_timerBarImageView` is the image view that contains the vertical image line / `_timerBarSlderCell` is the NSSlider's cell (subclassed)

PS: the NSSlider is behind every object in that window, so that the user can't see it. You can't `setHidden:YES` on it because the `drawKnob` method will not be called.

Answer (score 0):

You can just override `drawRect:`, as when subclassing `NSView`, except in your implementation, use `[self doubleValue]` to determine where to draw the line.  However, I don't see the point of subclassing `NSSlider` in this case.  A custom `NSView` could have a property that determines where to draw the line, and then other code could set that property or bind to it.

Comment: and what do I do with the doubleValue? I want to use a `NSSlider` because I can easily set the `Min Value` to 0 and `Max Value` to the track's length (in seconds), so that I don't need to worry about where should I draw the image (the knob is already the line). Every second that goes by the knob is dragged (programmatically) to work as a time bar.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a vertical split view to me with a 1 pixel wide divider. You might try that. There's a method to set the position of the divider so it would be easy to move as you need. And you can make the divider 1 pixel by creating a subclass of NSSplitview and overriding the dividerThickness method to return 1. Then you just set the background of the 2 subviews to black and there you go. It's easy to try so maybe it will work for you. Good luck.