# Change NSSlider bar color

Tags: cocoa, swift, nsslider

I've got an NSWindow and an horizontal NSSlider.

**I'd like to change the color of the right part of the slider bar when the window background color changes.**

[image]

[image]

Currently, the right part of the bar isn't visible anymore when the window background is dark.

*Note: the window background is actually a gradient I'm drawing by overriding `drawRect` in a subclass of the window's view.*

I thought I could change the slider bar fill color by subclassing `NSSliderCell` and overriding some method like `drawBarInside` but I don't understand how it works: should I make a little square image and draw it repeatedly in the rect after the knob? Or maybe just draw a colored line? I've never done this before.

I've looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14347973/how-to-create-a-custom-nsslider-with-a-transparent-middle-bar-and-custom-knob-si) and it's interesting but it's about drawing the knob and I don't need that for now.

I also had a look at [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985816/custom-nsslidercell) which seemed very promising, but when I try to mimic this code my slider bar just disappears...

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19731098/how-to-customize-a-nsslider) they use `drawWithFrame` and it looks interesting but again I'm not sure how it works.

I would like to do this with my own code instead of using a library. Could somebody give me a hint about how to do this please? :)

*I'm doing this in Swift but I can read/use Objective-C if necessary.*

Comment: I guess you can't access those attributes from the standard interface. The 2nd link looks promising. I guess you should get it running. Basically a slider is a simple view where the knob follows drag-n-drop.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is correct, you have to subclass the `NSSliderCell` class to **redraw the bar** or the **knob**.

`NSRect` is just a rectangular container, you have to draw inside this container. I made an example based on an custom `NSLevelIndicator` that I have in one of my program.

First you need to calculate the position of the knob. You must pay attention to the control minimum and maximum value.
Next you draw a  `NSBezierPath` for the background and another for the left part.

[image: Custom NSSlider control bar]

```
#import "MyCustomSlider.h"

@implementation MyCustomSlider

- (void)drawBarInside:(NSRect)rect flipped:(BOOL)flipped {

//  [super drawBarInside:rect flipped:flipped];

    rect.size.height = 5.0;

    // Bar radius
    CGFloat barRadius = 2.5;

    // Knob position depending on control min/max value and current control value.
    CGFloat value = ([self doubleValue]  - [self minValue]) / ([self maxValue] - [self minValue]);

    // Final Left Part Width
    CGFloat finalWidth = value * ([[self controlView] frame].size.width - 8);

    // Left Part Rect
    NSRect leftRect = rect;
    leftRect.size.width = finalWidth;

    NSLog(@"- Current Rect:%@ \n- Value:%f \n- Final Width:%f", NSStringFromRect(rect), value, finalWidth);

    // Draw background track
    NSBezierPath* bg = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect: rect xRadius: barRadius yRadius: barRadius];
    [NSColor.orangeColor setFill];
    [bg fill];

    // Draw active track
    NSBezierPath* active = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect: leftRect xRadius: barRadius yRadius: barRadius];
    [NSColor.purpleColor setFill];
    [active fill];


}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it looks very helpful. I will adapt this to Swift and test it as soon as I can.

Comment: Works like a charm! I'm marking your answer as accepted, and I'm updating mine with the Swift version I made from your example. Thank you !

Comment: There's *sometimes* a little blur like [this](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s89/sh/3815fed6-c28a-43ba-a8a5-ebe11c96f90f/47918faa41523aa7cfa4c5a0e962ae35/deep/0/BoomBox.png) on the left of the knob when it moves. Do you think I need to force the UI to refresh somewhere?

Comment: If you speak of the effect on the left of the knob, you can adjust the last value (8), normally its the knob width: `CGFloat finalWidth = value * ([[self controlView] frame].size.width - 8);`

Comment: Thanks, but this seems to have ghosting colors when pulling the circle.

Comment: Thanks for the solution! I notice some off-center and added this line: rect.origin.y = rect.origin.y + 1;

Comment: The ghosting is happening because the given solution overrides aRect height for whatever reason. See improved answer below.

Comment: @videolist where is the improved solution posted? You mean the solution posted by Morten?

Answer (score 16):

First, I created an image of a slider bar and copied it in my project.

Then I used this image in the `drawBarInside` method to draw in the bar `rect` *before* the normal one, so we'll see only the remainder part (I wanted to keep the blue part intact).

This has to be done in a subclass of `NSSliderCell`:

```
class CustomSliderCell: NSSliderCell {

    let bar: NSImage

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.bar = NSImage(named: "bar")!
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func drawBarInside(aRect: NSRect, flipped: Bool) {
        var rect = aRect
        rect.size = NSSize(width: rect.width, height: 3)
        self.bar.drawInRect(rect)
        super.drawBarInside(rect, flipped: flipped)
    }

}
```

Pro: it works. :)

Con: it removes the rounded edges of the bar and I haven't found a way to redraw this yet.

[image: custom nsslider]

**UPDATE:**

I made a Swift version of the accepted answer, it works very well:

```
class CustomSliderCell: NSSliderCell {

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func drawBarInside(aRect: NSRect, flipped: Bool) {
        var rect = aRect
        rect.size.height = CGFloat(5)
        let barRadius = CGFloat(2.5)
        let value = CGFloat((self.doubleValue - self.minValue) / (self.maxValue - self.minValue))
        let finalWidth = CGFloat(value * (self.controlView!.frame.size.width - 8))
        var leftRect = rect
        leftRect.size.width = finalWidth
        let bg = NSBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, xRadius: barRadius, yRadius: barRadius)
        NSColor.orangeColor().setFill()
        bg.fill()
        let active = NSBezierPath(roundedRect: leftRect, xRadius: barRadius, yRadius: barRadius)
        NSColor.purpleColor().setFill()
        active.fill()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Swift 5

```
class CustomSliderCell: NSSliderCell {
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func drawBar(inside aRect: NSRect, flipped: Bool) {
        var rect = aRect
        rect.size.height = CGFloat(5)
        let barRadius = CGFloat(2.5)
        let value = CGFloat((self.doubleValue - self.minValue) / (self.maxValue - self.minValue))
        let finalWidth = CGFloat(value * (self.controlView!.frame.size.width - 8))
        var leftRect = rect
        leftRect.size.width = finalWidth
        let bg = NSBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, xRadius: barRadius, yRadius: barRadius)
        NSColor.orange.setFill()
        bg.fill()
        let active = NSBezierPath(roundedRect: leftRect, xRadius: barRadius, yRadius: barRadius)
        NSColor.purple.setFill()
        active.fill()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I have achieved this without redraw or override cell at all. Using "False color" filter seems work very well and it is only a few codes!

```
class RLSlider: NSSlider {
init() {
    super.init(frame: NSZeroRect)
    addFilter()
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)
    addFilter()
}

func addFilter() {
    let colorFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIFalseColor")!
    colorFilter.setDefaults()
    colorFilter.setValue(CIColor(cgColor: NSColor.white.cgColor), forKey: "inputColor0")
    colorFilter.setValue(CIColor(cgColor: NSColor.yellow.cgColor), forKey: "inputColor1")

//        colorFilter.setValue(CIColor(cgColor: NSColor.yellow.cgColor), forKey: "inputColor0")
//        colorFilter.setValue(CIColor(cgColor: NSColor.yellow.cgColor), forKey: "inputColor1")

    self.contentFilters = [colorFilter]
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: This won't let you get the exact color you want and it will replace the knob color as well.